# return product name in new column for each row based on if an individual product column in each row contains a 1

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am receiving sales data in a format like:
[image]

I'd like to at least get in the format of: 
[image]

Or even better: 
[image]

I'm looking to do this in Google Sheets, but if that's not an option I'm looking to use bigquery.

Thank  you.

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below options (BigQuery)

[image]

with output

[image]

Or even better:

[image]

with output

[image]

Comment: It is still readable. Please zoom out a bit.

Comment: I found this is the only way for me to "fight" against posting images in question's posts. but at the same time, I want my answer still be useful :o)